# How to convert a nested lists to dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I'm have a nested list I would like to convert to a dataframe.

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a")
iter2 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "b")
All <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)

df <- data.frame(t(sapply(All,c))) # Convert list to dataframe
```

But my problem is that `df$iter1` returns a list instead of a dataframe, any idea ?

```
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"

> df$item1
$iter1
[1] 1

$iter2
[1] 1
```

I have the same problem when converting with `do.call` : `df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, All))` but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: df$iter1 cannot return a data.frame! An item of a data.frame can be a vector or a list. By the way df is a dataframe but its items are lists not vectors. Suppose you want them to be vectors of numeric and character values respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = unique(unlist(lapply(All, names)))
mydf = setNames(object = data.frame(lapply(temp, function(nm)
    unlist(lapply(All, function(x) x[[nm]])))), nm = temp)

mydf
#      item1 item2
#iter1     1     a
#iter2     1     b
```

OR

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(All, data.frame))
#      item1 item2
#iter1     1     a
#iter2     1     b
```

OR

```
data.table::rbindlist(All, idcol = TRUE)
#     .id item1 item2
#1: iter1     1     a
#2: iter2     1     b
```

Comment: For the last one: That's the perfect way @d.b! And as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(All, idcol = TRUE)) converts it to a data frame if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Would lapply do what you want ?:

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a")
iter2 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "b")
All <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
```

And then:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(All, unlist))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ iter1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","a": 1 2
 $ iter2: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","b": 1 2
```

Comment: They are factors. And if you provide stringsAsFactors = F, they all are coerced to characters. I think first columns chould be numeric (1,1) and the second character (a, b)?

Comment: You could transpose and the make the column numeric perhaps ?

Comment: what I would like is a dataframe so that `df$item1` returns a dataframe with column `item1`.

Comment: That is a way, but not an R way. What if you have 100 columns?

Comment: @SerhatCevikel: Sure, not very generic

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the first column to be a numeric vector as 1,1 and the second column to be a character vector as "a" and "b"?

How about this:

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "a")
iter2 <- list(item1 = 1, item2 = "b")
All <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)

extract <- function(x, listx) sapply(listx, "[[", x)

df <- lapply(1:2, extract, All)
df <- as.data.frame(df, col.names = names(All), stringsAsFactors = F)
df
```

And if you want a one-liner:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:2, function(x, listx) sapply(listx, "[[", x), All), col.names = names(All), stringsAsFactors = F)
df
```

Comment: You have iter1, iter2 as both col and row names, but I guess they belong on rows only, while cols should have item1, item2.