# Flatten nested dataframe of tibbles with missing data

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-lists

I have a nested dataframe of tibbles with the following structure:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = list(structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"
), var2 = c(1L, 1L), var3 = c(9L, 9L), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, 
    var6 = c("Don’t shortchange public trust in science", NA), 
    var7 = c("11 September 2020", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 
1L), var3 = c(9L, 9L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Tailoring immunotherapy with liquid biopsy", 
"Pseudovirus for immunotherapy"), var7 = c("18 September 2020", 
"10 August 2020"), var8 = c("News & Views", "News & Views")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(2L, 2L), var3 = c(9L, 9L
    ), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Before clicking the ‘submit’ button", 
    NA), var7 = c("23 September 2021", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(2L, 
2L), var3 = c(9L, 9L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Immunoradiotherapy goes club(bing)", 
"Splitting signals drives CARs further"), var7 = c("20 September 2021", 
"23 September 2021"), var8 = c("News & Views", "News & Views"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), V2 = list(structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 
1L), var3 = c(10L, 10L), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("What next for postdocs?", 
NA), var7 = c("09 October 2020", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 1L), 
    var3 = c(10L, 10L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Optimizing CARs for ocular delivery", 
    "mtDNA mutations help support cancer cells"), var7 = c("12 October 2020", 
    "19 October 2020"), var8 = c("News & Views", "News & Views"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(2L, 2L), 
    var3 = c(10L, 10L), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("The labors of referees", 
    NA), var7 = c("22 October 2021", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(2L, 
2L), var3 = c(10L, 10L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("A PRC1–RNF2 knockout punch for cancer", 
"A quick guide for clinical oncology"), var7 = c("22 October 2021", 
"22 October 2021"), var8 = c("News & Views", "News & Views")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), V3 = list(structure(list(
    var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 1L), var3 = c(11L, 11L
    ), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Rise of the preprints", 
    NA), var7 = c("17 November 2020", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 
1L), var3 = c(11L, 11L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Future directions in preclinical and translational cancer neuroscience research", 
NA), var7 = c("17 November 2020", NA), var8 = c("Comment", NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(c("result.1", 
"result.2"), NULL)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("result.1", "result.2"), NULL))), V4 = list(structure(list(
    var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 1L), var3 = c(12L, 12L
    ), var4 = c(1L, 1L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Tackling the shadow pandemic", 
    NA), var7 = c("16 December 2020", NA), var8 = c("Editorial", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), structure(list(var1 = c("tst", "tst"), var2 = c(1L, 
1L), var3 = c(12L, 12L), var4 = c(2L, 2L), var5 = 1:2, var6 = c("Mutagenic exposures shape immunotherapy responses", 
"How to kill Treg cells for immunotherapy"), var7 = c("16 December 2020", 
"16 December 2020"), var8 = c("News & Views", "News & Views")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(c(NA, 
NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(c("result.1", "result.2"), 
    NULL)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("result.1", "result.2"), NULL))), V5 = list(structure(c(NA, 
NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(c("result.1", "result.2"), 
    NULL)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("result.1", "result.2"), NULL)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("result.1", "result.2"), NULL)), structure(c(NA, NA), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("result.1", "result.2"), NULL)))), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000015e6de41ef0>)
```

For the first two columns of tibbles I am able to use `bind_rows` and get the desired output:

```
bind_rows(bind_rows(df$V1),bind_rows(df$V2))
```

[image: Desired output]

When I try to bind additional rows with missing information `bind_rows` gives an error:

```
bind_rows(bind_rows(df$V1),bind_rows(df$V2),bind_rows(df$V3))
```

> Error: Argument 3 must have names.

I was able to get this far using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720363/how-to-convert-a-nested-lists-to-dataframe-in-r). I was thinking of trying to use the `map` function like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505923/error-in-bind-rows-x-id-argument-1-must-have-names), but I cannot get it to work.

Edit: updated error code

Answer (score 0):

seems to work for me:

```
> z1 <- bind_rows(bind_rows(df$V1),bind_rows(df$V2),bind_rows(df$V2))
> str(z1)
tibble [24 x 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ var1: chr [1:24] "tst" "tst" "tst" "tst" ...
 $ var2: int [1:24] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ var3: int [1:24] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 ...
 $ var4: int [1:24] 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ var5: int [1:24] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ var6: chr [1:24] "Don’t shortchange public trust in science" NA "Tailoring immunotherapy with liquid biopsy" "Pseudovirus for immunotherapy" ...
 $ var7: chr [1:24] "11 September 2020" NA "18 September 2020" "10 August 2020" ...
 $ var8: chr [1:24] "Editorial" NA "News & Views" "News & Views" ...
```

Comment: Sorry it should be: `bind_rows(bind_rows(df$V1),bind_rows(df$V2),bind_rows(df$V3))`