# Convert a list with inconsistent naming to a data frame, with variable depth

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Consider the following list:

```r
x <- list("a" = list("b", "c"),
          "d" = list("e", "f" = list("g", "h")),
          "i" = list("j", "k" = list("l" = list("m", "n" = list("o", "p")))))
```

It is worth noting that:

- Not all names and elements are going to be of one character
- There is an undetermined level of nesting *a priori*.

Given `x`, my aim is to output the data frame:

```
y <- data.frame(
  main_level = c(rep("a", 2), rep("d", 3), rep("i", 4)),
  level1 = c("b", "c", "e", rep("f", 2), "j", rep("k", 3)),
  level2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "g", "h", NA, "l", "l", "l"),
  level3 = c(NA, NA, NA,  NA,  NA, NA, "m", "n", "n"), 
  level4 = c(NA, NA, NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA, "o", "p")
)
> y
  main_level level1 level2 level3 level4
1          a      b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2          a      c   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3          d      e   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4          d      f      g   <NA>   <NA>
5          d      f      h   <NA>   <NA>
6          i      j   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
7          i      k      l      m   <NA>
8          i      k      l      n      o
9          i      k      l      n      p
```

**NOTE** that a typo was corrected in `y` above.

The above implies that there will be a variable number of columns as well, depending on the depth of the nesting.

Solutions online that I've found, when it comes to nested lists, assume that the list naming structure is more or less consistent, which is of course not the case here; or that the list depth is identical. For instance, the solutions at [How to convert a nested lists to dataframe in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720363/how-to-convert-a-nested-lists-to-dataframe-in-r) and [Converting nested list to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe) do not apply because they are much more consistent in their naming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way mainly relying on `rrapply`:

```r
rrapply::rrapply(x, how = "melt") |>
  apply(1, function(row){
    newrow <- row[grep("[A-Za-z]", row)]
    length(newrow) <- purrr::vec_depth(x) - 1
    newrow
  }) |> 
  t() |> as.data.frame() |>
  `colnames<-`(c("main_level", paste0("level", 1:4)))
```

output

```r
  main_level level1 level2 level3 level4
1          a      b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2          a      c   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3          d      e   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4          d      f      g   <NA>   <NA>
5          d      f      h   <NA>   <NA>
6          i      j   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
7          i      k      l      m   <NA>
8          i      k      l      n      o
9          i      k      l      n      p
```

Note that so far it is quite crude. There might be a better way to reshape the output of `rrapply`. For instance, `row[grep("[A-Za-z]", row)]` may not work every time. I have also not tested whether `length(newrow) <- purrr::vec_depth(x) - 1` is a good way of guessing the length, but it works here.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a recursive function that has no assumptions other than the structure you described:

```r
list_to_df <- function(l) {
  
  leaves <- list()
  
  go_deeper <- function(l, index=1, path=NULL) {

    # we can still go deeper    
    if (is.list(l[[index]])) {
      
      path <- c(path, names(l)[index])
      l <- l[[index]]
      
      lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) go_deeper(l, i, path))

    # this is the final node (leaf)      
    } else {
      
      leaves <<- c(leaves, list(c(path, l[[index]])))
    }
  }
  
  # this saves the paths to each last node (leaf) in 'leaves' as a side effect
  go_deeper(list(l))
  
  # now just make a data frame from the 'leaves' list
  len.max <- max(lengths(leaves))
  leaves <- sapply(leaves, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, len.max-length(x))))
  leaves <- as.data.frame(t(leaves))
  names(leaves) <- c('main_level', paste0('level', seq_len(ncol(leaves)-1)))
  
  leaves 
}
```

```r
list_to_df(x)
#   main_level level1 level2 level3 level4
# 1          a      b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2          a      c   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 3          d      e   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 4          d      f      g   <NA>   <NA>
# 5          d      f      h   <NA>   <NA>
# 6          i      j   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 7          i      k      l      m   <NA>
# 8          i      k      l      n      o
# 9          i      k      l      n      p
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more robust approach using `rrapply()` inspired by Maël's answer:

- Set all missing/empty names in the nested list to `NA`
- Melt to a long data.frame with the node paths as data.frame rows
- Replace the first `NA` on each node path by its leaf value (`value` column)

```
library(rrapply)

x1 <- rrapply(x, f = \(x, .xname) ifelse(grepl("^\\d*$", .xname), NA, .xname), how = "names")
x2 <- rrapply(x1, how = "melt")  
x3 <- apply(x2, 1, \(x){ x[is.na(x)][1] <- x[["value"]]; x })

as.data.frame(t(x3[-nrow(x3), ]))

#>   L1 L2   L3   L4   L5
#> 1  a  b <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2  a  c <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 3  d  e <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 4  d  f    g <NA> <NA>
#> 5  d  f    h <NA> <NA>
#> 6  i  j <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 7  i  k    l    m <NA>
#> 8  i  k    l    n    o
#> 9  i  k    l    n    p
```